Is there a way to make Angular proxy cancel ASP.NET Core request?
In order to reproduce the issue, please create a brand new Angular + ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2022. Add the method below to the sample WeatherForecastController. The method waits 100 seconds and listens to a CancellationToken.
When the project is launched the API is hosted at https://localhost:7073/ while the Angular app is hosted at https://localhost:4200/. Angular features a proxy that is configured by proxy.conf.js. It maps requests from Angular's domain/port to app's domain/port.
If one tries to load https://localhost:7073/weatherforecast/test in a browser, the method will start to wait 100 seconds. Canceling browser page load triggers the method's CancellationToken as expected.
On the other hand, if one tries to load https://localhost:4200/weatherforecast/test, the Test() method is triggered as expected and it starts its 100 second wait. However, canceling browser page load has no effect. The method continues to run until completion.
Is there a way to tweak/configure Angular's proxy so that cancelled requests are carried over on the ASP.NET Core side? Is this just a plain bug? Are there any workarounds?
[HttpGet, Route("test")]
public async Task Test(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  try
  {
    await Task.Delay(100_000, cancellationToken);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
  }
}

